# Node.js - delete specific functions from an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, function, module, anonymous-function

Given an array of named functions, how can I delete all but a specified one? The functions are exported e.g. exports.foo. To mock an example:

```
var test = [];
test.push(foo = function(){});
test.push(bar = function(){});
console.log(test);
```

Logs:

```
[ [Function], [Function] ]
```

How can I delete all functions except a specified one e.g. bar?

---

EDIT: Some additional context - I have a set of plugins (functions) that get loaded automatically in to an array. As part of my Mocha tests, I wish to test each one individually, hence wanting to drop all but a specified function.

Comment: If you want to test each individually, I'd suggest copying the fn you want and testing that instead.

Comment: Something like `fnToTest = array.someFn'

Comment: OK, understood. I think even better, I need to extend my main loader class to be more test orientated e.g. I can specify a plugin to load, or all get loaded. Thanks for the feedback - very helpful :)

Comment: Yes, I think that would make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to question why you'd want to do this, but if you're set on doing it, this is how I'd approach it:

```
function deleteAllButThis(fn, arr){


  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     //if fn in array does NOT match fn passed in, 
     if (fn !== arr[i]) {
       arr.splice(i, 1); //remove current array item
     }
  }

  return arr;

}
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
deleteAllButThis(foo, test);
```